# Function parameter is not defined onclick in KendoGrid, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'd appreciate if someone can advise on my issue.

In my `.cshtml` view I have:

```
<a class="k-button accountSearch"></a>

<div class="accountsWindow" hidden="hidden">
   <div class="accountsGrid">
       @Html.Partial("AccountsGrid", context.CustomerAccounts)
   </div>
</div>
<script>
       function getCustomerAccount(iban) {        
        alert(iban);       
    };
</script>
```

When the above link with class `k-button accountSearch` is clicked `KendoWindow` appears:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var accwindow = $(".accountsWindow");
        acc = $(".accountSearch")
                .on("click", function () {
                    accwindow.data("kendoWindow").open();
                });

        if (!accwindow.data("kendoWindow")) {
            accwindow.kendoWindow({               
                actions: [
                    ...
                ]
            });
        }
});
```

The grid is rendered as partial (`AccountsGrid.cshtml`)and appears in popup `kendoWindow`:

```
@model IEnumerable<DAL.Model.CustomerAccount>

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
      .Name("AccountsGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {              
          columns.Bound(u => u.IBAN).Template(@<text> <a onclick="getCustomerAccount(@item.IBAN)">@item.IBAN</a> </text>).Title("IBAN").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" });
      })
    .Pageable()  
    )
```

I want to get the model value `@item.IBAN` passing in with function `getCustomerAccount(@item.IBAN)`. The error occurs when function is called, it says:

```
   US11223344 is not defined
```

where `US11223344` is the `@item.IBAN` value and is correct but why there is an error? I dont see the alert as well.

Comment: I guess you should include your value in quotes, like this `...onclick="getCustomerAccount('@item.IBAN')"...`, because you want to pass string eventually, and not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBAN is a string value so u have to add ''

```
<a onclick="getCustomerAccount('@item.IBAN')">@item.IBAN</a>
```